# javascript counter not adding 1 but adding 2 without intending to

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create counter that increase by one each time as follow:

```
var imnum=0;
(function changeImage(){
    ++imnum;
   $( ".slider" ).fadeOut( 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $('#home-slider-im').attr("src",images[imnum]);
    $('#home-slider-t').attr("src", imagesText[imnum]);

    $( ".slider" ).fadeIn( 2000, function() {
      // Animation complete
    });

    console.log(imnum);
    setTimeout(changeImage,10000)

})})();
```

but the console log output is 1 3 7 15... not 1 2 3 4... am I doing something wrong? what is it? how to fix it?

Comment: Where else is `imnum` used? You've not disclosed how this (bad) Global variable is declared or what other side effects may be causing this.

Comment: How many `.slider` elements do you have? The callback gets called once *per element*. If you have more than one, you'll call `setTimeout` more than once in response to the first change.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: @RandyCasburn it is declared right before the function changeImage() and I included it in my question

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your callback is called for every matched element. Based on your output, it looks like you have two elements with class `.slider`, so it's calling `setTimeout()` twice every time the function is called. Instead, you could just have the timeout outside of the callback and wait for a little bit longer:

```
var imnum=0;
(function changeImage(){
    ++imnum;
   $( ".slider" ).fadeOut( 5000, function() {

    // Animation complete.
    $('#home-slider-im').attr("src",images[imnum]);
    $('#home-slider-t').attr("src", imagesText[imnum]);


   // $(this).stop();
    $( ".slider" ).fadeIn( 2000, function() {
      // Animation complete
    });
    //alert(i);
   // console.log(i);

 });
 setTimeout(changeImage,15000)
 console.log(imnum);

})();
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you have more than one element with `class="slider"`. The `fadeOut` callback will get called for **each** element that fades out. So if you have (say) two, the first call to `changeImage` will trigger the callback twice...and things will rapidly accelerate from there. :-)

Since your fadeout is 5000ms and your fadein is 2000ms and your delay between images is 10000ms, just move the `setTimeout` outside the `fadeOut` callback:

```
var imnum = 0;
(function changeImage() {
    ++imnum;
    $(".slider").fadeOut(5000, function() {

        // Animation complete.
        $('#home-slider-im').attr("src", images[imnum]);
        $('#home-slider-t').attr("src", imagesText[imnum]);


        // $(this).stop();
        $(".slider").fadeIn(2000, function() {
            // Animation complete
        });
        //alert(i);
        // console.log(i);
    });

    // *** Outside the callback
    console.log(imnum);
    setTimeout(changeImage, 10000)
})();
```

*(I've also updated that to have consistent curly brace notation and indentation, which aids tremendously with readability.)*

---

Side note: You appear to be getting the image information from an array, but always increasing the `imnum` variable and not checking whether it wraps around. This trick may be useful:

```
imnum = (imnum + 1) % images.length;
```

That will wrap back to 0 when it gets to the end of the array.

Side note 2: You seem to have parallel arrays (`images` and `imagesText`). I'd suggest using a *singel* array of objects instead:

```
var images = [
    {text: "text for the image 1", src: "http://example.com/img/1"},
    {text: "text for the image 2", src: "http://example.com/img/2"},
    {text: "text for the image 3", src: "http://example.com/img/3"}
];
```

then

```
$('#home-slider-im').attr("src", images[imnum].src);
$('#home-slider-t').attr("src", images[imnum].text);
```